# Force Firefox to use xdg-open to open downloaded files

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, xdg-open

Firefox in Kubuntu is broken, as it doesn't follow the system default applications that I can configure using "file associations" in the KDE Control Module. For example, it wants to open folders with K4dirstat, videos in itself and PDF files with [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP).

I want Firefox to download everything (or almost everything) by default, and then when I double click the downloaded file in Firefox I want it do open using [xdg-open](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) (or using the application `xdg-open` would use), including "open the containing folder" thing.

My question is similar to this question from 2011: *[Firefox: open downloaded files with system default application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79592/firefox-open-downloaded-files-with-system-default-application)*

But I want "save file" marked in that window, and later open with a sane application from within Firefox.

This unanswered question also seems related, as if it is possible to do what I want. I think that other question is answered too: *https://askubuntu.com/questions/546113/change-default-application-for-a-file-type-in-dolphin-and-firefox*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox application associations not working in the 'Downloads' window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20015/firefox-application-associations-not-working-in-the-downloads-window)

Comment: I don't remember finding that question when I originally searched. The only diferences seems to be I want it using the xdg-open option by default if I didn't set anything different, and I want it to download by default, but yeah, it seems very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is exactly what is asked. I will be posting on
how to make Firefox downloads list open a file in a desired application.

Some newly installed applications take over the "default" status in Firefox's `about:preferences` instead of the per-filetype normal application set at system level (e.g. Palemoon takes over as default instead of gwenview for JPEG files, [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) or File Roller takes over instead of Okular for a PDF file.).

"Always ask" is the choice that should be used in this case and then trying to create a per-user file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` with the lines:

```
[MIME Cache]
application/pdf=okularApplication_pdf.desktop
```

The disadvantage of the above is that it is a per-file-type setting. To have a solution for all files (as said in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/55174/47206) answer), run:

```
cd .local/share/applications/
ln -s mimeapps.list defaults.list
```

In case this stops working: see that the undesired application is not again selected under `about:preferences`: be sure "Always ask" is selected there. Setting manually a different program (even the default for your file-type at system level, but which is not marked as "default" in the list for your file under `about:preferences`) might not work.

---

**Tested** in Firefox 60.0 in Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: also posted under the question to which this seem a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/1039160/47206.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't mark as answered because I went back to windows a few months after asking the question (in no small part due to this specific issue) and I can't test it anymore. I might return to linux and if I face the same issue I will give this a try. Thank you anyway.