# Firefox wants to open everything with gvim!

Tags: 12.04, firefox

Whenever I click a download link in Firefox (Ffox 38, on Ubuntu 12.04LTS) such as a PDF, I get

[image: screenshot 1]

And there's nothing more sensible than GVim in the Open With menu.

When I look in about:preferences, I see

[image: screenshot 2]

Which seems to imply it's aware of a document viewer application, but then it's not giving me that option when it opens a PDF...?

I've used PDF here as an example, it's the same with other formats, e.g. it also offers to open tar files with Gvim...

**How can I get Firefox 38 to correctly populate the Open with drop-down?**

(nb. I'm aware that this has been [asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79592/firefox-open-downloaded-files-with-system-default-application?lq=1) but those solutions only work for earlier versions of Firefox, so are irrelevant.)

---

EDIT: To be clear, my desktop system (Gnome Shell) does not have a problem opening files; it's just Firefox.

e.g.

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
evince.desktop
```

Comment: Try reset firefox to default settings,  helped in some cases (different from your problem). I was lazy exporting bookmarks etc. but it helped. OR try creating new profile (which is very unlikely to help, but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using " xdg-mime " you should be able to change the default application from browsers. Please look at [this](http://blog.radevic.com/2012/02/how-to-set-default-apps-aka-how-to-use.html) link for more info.

**EDIT:** I wrongly pasted some comments here (Thanks artfulrobot for pointing that). Removed them now. Please look at the link mentioned above for changing the application preference.

Comment: Thanks. Specifically for me, inspecting `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` showed that under `application/octet-stream` I had gvim and totem (?!) listed. As that mimetype is going to match all binary data it was taking over, unless there was a more specific match. Deleting that line from that file and restarting Firefox fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Delete or rename your `mimeTypes.rdf` file, then restart Firefox.  The `mimeTypes.rdf` file will be located somewhere in the `~/.mozilla` directory.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried that (`find ~/.mozilla -name mimeTypes.rdf -delete`) but it didn't solve the problem :-(

Comment: Actually, it's fixed it for PDFs, but not other files (e.g. .tgz) - still wants to open these with Gvim!